Bluetooth not working after upgrade to 24.04
Solved. I don't know why, but somehow this solved my problem:
https://www.reddit.com/r/ASUS/comments/he7ci7/comment/g1przej/?context=3
My bluetooth, which was working well in Ubuntu 23.10, is not working after upgrade to 24.04.
user@machine sudo systemctl status bluetooth.service
○ bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead)
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)

okt. 21 19:10:03 lars-lenovo systemd[1]: bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service was skipped because of an unmet condition ch>
okt. 21 19:10:40 lars-lenovo systemd[1]: bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service was skipped because of an unmet condition ch>
okt. 21 19:16:37 lars-lenovo systemd[1]: bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service was skipped because of an unmet condition ch>
lines 1-8/8 (END)

user@machine dmesg | grep -i bluetooth shows
sudo dmesg | grep -i bluetooth
[ 1472.985538] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[ 1472.985596] NET: Registered PF_BLUETOOTH protocol family
[ 1472.985598] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[ 1472.985603] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[ 1472.985605] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[ 1472.985611] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized

name@machine lsusb
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 13d3:56fb IMC Networks Integrated Camera
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 1a40:0101 Terminus Technology Inc. Hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 2109:0103 VIA Labs, Inc. USB 2.0 BILLBOARD
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 046d:c534 Logitech, Inc. Nano Receiver
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub

I've read and tried tips from several threads at askubuntu.com plus this one, to no avail.
https://www.makeuseof.com/fix-bluetooth-connectivity-issues-in-ubuntu/
I've also reboot several times during my trial and error. What are my next sensible steps?
